# Changing a recurring contribution with multiple line items

Tags: recurring-contributions, iats, line-items

CiviCRM 4.7.22
WordPress 4.8.1
iATSPayments

I am not sure if this should be asked in this exchange or the iATS github.

We have a donor with a recurring donation that was $125 a month, with $50 for Line Item 1, $50 for Line Item 2, and $25 for Line Item 3. Several months ago they wanted to make it $50 for all three funds. So they went into their recurring contribution and edited it to be $150 instead of $125. Since then, it is processing it at $150 but it is not changing the Line Item Table to show $50 for each fund.

I thought that it used to just look at the previous contribution for the Line Item info. So I edited the line item table with $50 for each fund. But it continues to do the next recurring as $50, $50, $25.

I also changed the Invoice Id in the recurring table (see screenshot) to a contribution that I had edited. Thinking that it must look at that invoice id for future recurring details. But it still processes $50, $50, $25.
[image]

Any ideas where it refers to for a template to populate recurring Line Items? How can I make this work correctly from here forward?

Can I change the start date to the date of a correct donation? Does it use the first contribution as the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.6.x branch of the iATS extension is using contribution repeattransaction API -> to get the details of the contribution and its line items that need to be repeated;

If a recurring contribution has lineItems associated with it - we don't allow updating it in the GUI:

[image]

You can (as you noted) update this in the backend -> however -> repeattransaction API will continue to use the lineItems associated with the first contribution in a recurring series as the 'template';

Best solution in this case is to start a new recurring series -> with both the correct total amount and the correct break down; Two ways to do this:

1) ask the donor to initiate a new series on an online contribution page;

2) since you have the iATS customer token -> you can use phpMyAdmin to set up a new series - and attach the token to this. It's tricky in that you will need to touch a number of tables -> and possibly bookkeeping entries as well (if you care about those);

Comment: What are all the tables that I need to edit to set up a new series? Can I copy the Recurring entry and create a new Recurring entry with a new ID, with the last Invoice ID and date as the start, Then change the last Contribution/Line_Item to the new recurring ID and change/copy the iATS_customer_code entry to this Recurring ID?  We do not use Bookkeeping entries since they do not support Line Item details.

Comment: Top of my head: civicrm_contribution; civicrm_contribution_recur; civicrm_line_item; civicrm_iats_customer_codes; it's similar to the process of how one can migrate recurring series to iATS for processing; be careful;

Answer (score 1):

I believe the line item info comes from the FIRST recurring contribution, not the most recent one.

Comment: So if I change the start date on the recurring contribution table, will that point it to contribution with the correct line item template?

Comment: It might be a worth a discussion about changing this to make recurring contribution edits easier.

Comment: @CarlMiller I agree!  However, it's a pretty difficult space to work in - different payment processors have different rules - e.g. you can't increase a price by more than 20% in PayPal every x number of days.  So for now, it's just left as an unsupported action.